# How to join two tables in cakephp 3.x with a custom fieldname?

Tags: join, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have one table called countries which has a field i.e ID with primary key and the other table is customers which has a field called primary_country. I want to join both the tables in cakephp way, but always it is taking customers.country_id which is not present in the table. I am using primary_country because the table also has alternate_country field. so i can't use country_id. Please provide me any solution so that I can fetch the country names on the basis of primary_country and alternate_country.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to modify your table object with the foreign key, as mentionned here:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

It could be something like that, in your case :

```
class CustomersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Countries')
            ->setForeignKey('primary_country');
    }
}
```

But i must say that if your model is still under conception, you may want to make an third table customer_countries and make an 'hasMany' relation between 'customers' and 'countries'. Limiting records for one customer to only two countries, and ordering them between 'primary' and 'alternate' is part of you business logic.